# What to use : Excel VS MySql/MongoDB [Java]

Tags: java, mysql

I am going to make a business application for my father to make GST(Goods and Services Tax) filing easier. I have the design ready and I am going to use JavaFX.

- The user will enter the data in `tableview` and that data needs to be stored for future reference.
- The `tableview` needs to be converted to an excel file (gonna use Apache POI). The excel file will be sent to a C.A who will file GST on my father's behalf.
- The application will need to import/export data into/from the `tableview` and edit the data as necessary.

I have 2 options :

1. Store/retrieve data from `MySQL` to `tableview`, update it according to the user's will and later export the data into excel files for sending it to C.A.
2. Store/retrieve data from excel files to `tableview`, update it according to the user's will and send the excel file to C.A.

I am planning to expand the application into a complete Business software that can manage entire business.

What should I use?
Which one will be more efficient and why?

I hope I am able to convey my question (I ain't good at writing).

Comment: I definitely think you should separate persistence from export functionality so that you use a separate solution for storing data, you might for instance want to store more data than you need for the export. I also think that you should consider other options than MySql since it's a separate program, what about an embedded db like Sqlite or maybe a simple solution like a text file in csv, json or xml format could be enough.

Comment: Currently, it is going to have single user accessing the database at a time. But later on, its gonna be 2/3 or maybe even more. I want it to be ready for advancement.

SQLite seems to be good but how much can it be scaled to?? And if I use SQLite, can I transfer the DB to MySQL later (if needed).

Comment: I didn't understand that it was a multiuser application you aimed for since you considered using an excel file for persistence. Maybe MySql is a better choice them. I don't think moving from Sqlite to MySql is a concern compared to moving from a single to a multi-user design.

Comment: Oh so does that means that excel files won't be able to handle 2 users at a time? I didn't knew that. Thank you for helping out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question, since I have got the answer.

I'm going with SQLite for now as using csv or excel files is gonna consume a lot of resources (I tried it).

I am going to sync the .db file in drive using scripts from the application itself. MySQL is definitely better choice but I want to database to be used by 2 computers at a time (not in network) so I will have to pay for online database.

I will store the .db file and drive and will retrieve it whenever the application runs. In this way its going to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

In my own opinion it is more efficient and have more posibilities to explotes the data using MySQL, because reading and writing an Excel file will take a lot of time and it is slower.